# How can I add AI to Tic-Tac-Toe game using a random number generator in python?

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

This is one of my first programs for an online Python course I am taking. I've cobbled together some code that does most of the work but I am still having trouble getting my computer player move to use the random number library and read them to the board. I've tried moving the code within `DrawMove()` directly into the main code with no luck. Currently I have it set up so that two players can play against each other but I want to add `randrange` to the 'X' player so that the player can play against the computer.

```
import itertools
from random import randrange

board = [[1,2,3],
         [4,'X',6],
         [7,8,9]]
   
         
def InitialBoard(board):
    print("+-------+-------+-------+\n|       |       |       |\n|  ",board[0][0],"  |  ",board[0][1],"  |  ",board[0][2],"  |")
    print("|       |       |       |\n+-------+-------+-------+\n|       |       |       |")
    print("|  ",board[1][0],"  |  ",'X',"  |  ",board[1][2],"  |\n|       |       |       |\n+-------+-------+-------+")
    print("|       |       |       |\n|  ",board[2][0],"  |  ",board[2][1],"  |  ",board[2][2],"  |\n|       |       |       |")
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    
def DisplayBoard(gameMap, playerMove, row, column):

    try:
        if board[row][column] == 'X' or board[row][column] == 'O':
            print("This space is occupied by X, please try another one.")
            return False
        gameMap[row][column] = playerMove #add parameters to our function
        for row, column in enumerate(gameMap):
            print("+-------+-------+-------+\n|       |       |       |\n|  ",board[0][0],"  |  ",board[0][1],"  |  ",board[0][2],"  |")
            print("|       |       |       |\n+-------+-------+-------+\n|       |       |       |")
            print("|  ",board[1][0],"  |  ",'X',"  |  ",board[1][2],"  |\n|       |       |       |\n+-------+-------+-------+")
            print("|       |       |       |\n|  ",board[2][0],"  |  ",board[2][1],"  |  ",board[2][2],"  |\n|       |       |       |")
            print("+-------+-------+-------+")
        return gameMap
    except IndexError: #handles index error
        print("Out of range, please choose a number between 0-2.")
        return False
    except Exception as e: #handles general errors, prints description of type of error
        print(str(e))
        return False


def VictoryFor(current_game):
   #horizontal
    for row in board:
     
        column1 = row[0] #all the same on top row
        column2 = row[1]
        column3 = row[2]
        if column1 == column2 == column3:#checks if top row same
            print(f"Player {row[0]} is the winner!")#f string is used to pass variables inside of curly braces
        

#vertical
    if board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0]:
        print("Winner in first column!")
        for row in board:
            print(row[0])
    elif board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1]:
        print("Winner in second column!")
        for row in board:
            print(row[1])
    elif board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2]:
        print("Winner in third column!")
        for row in board:
            print(row[2])

#diagonal
    if board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]:
        print("Diagonal Winner down!")
    if board[2][0] == board[1][1] == board[0][2]:
        print("Diagonal Winner up!")


def DrawMove(board):#computer move
           
    row_choice = int(randrange(2))
    columnn_choice = int(randrange(2))

#main
play = True 
players = ['X','O']#computer is X, player is O. Computer makes first move.
while play:
    board = [[1, 2, 3],
             [4,'X',6],
             [7, 8, 9]]
             
    game_won = False
    player_cycle = itertools.cycle(['X','O'])
    InitialBoard(board)
    while not game_won:
        current_player = 'O'#computer has made move in center of board, your turn now
        current_player = next(player_cycle)
        played = False
        while not played:
            print(f"Player: {current_player}")
            column_choice = int(input("Pick a column 0-2:"))
            row_choice = int(input("Pick a row 0-2:"))
            played = DisplayBoard(board, playerMove = current_player, row = row_choice, column = column_choice)
    if VictoryFor(board):
        game_won = True
        again = input("The game is over, play again? Type (y/n)")
        if again.lower() == "y":
            print("Restarting")
        elif again.lower() == "n":
            print("Goodbye")
            play = False
        else:
            play = False
```

Comment: The question is unclear for me. What is your specific programming problem?

Answer (score 1):

This may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but one place to start to consider your `board` variable as the "game state".

Rather than let the AI choose any row/column, it should only choose a row/column that is not already occupied.

So you could think of your board as an initial value, which eventually fills up with unplayable spaces, and rather than "random number" you can think of it as a random "draw" from this pool of choices. Think "draw from a deck of cards" more than "tell me a random number".

I think that this would be more efficient than hoping to randomly choose a valid position.

For example, in a trivial 1-row version of tic-tac-toe:

```
row1 = [1, 2, 3]
mask = [1, 1, 1] # initial state
# human places an X at position 2:
mask = update() # mask for row1 becomes [1, 0, 1]

# AI now can determine that position 2 is not a valid spot:
valid_spots = list(filter(bool, [i*j for i,j in zip(row1, mask)])) # [1,3]

# choose a valid spot from the available indexes
choice_index = random.randint(0, len(valid_spots)-1)
new_move = row1[choice_index]
```

Answer (score -1):

you are resetting the board every time your while play loop runs

Comment: That's a good comment but it doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: i put this down because the op has the random value used immediately then since they reset the board straight after that it could be perceived as not working